# concurrenthashmap java

Tags: java, concurrency

This seems wrong.

```
        static ConcurrentHashMap k; //multiple threads have access to k
         X o = k.get("LL");
         o.a = 6;
```

If multiple threads access k concurrently, and get k("LL"), then update (o.a = #) without k.put("ll",o), without synchronizing on 'o', or on 'k' what happens?

Comment: I believe (Yes, I'm not sure) a [concurrent modification exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) exception would raise on runtime when you try to set the a property from the X object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ConcurrentMap has conditional operations that guarantee atomic insert/removal and replacement of key/value pairs. Additionally, accessing a ConcurrentMap creates a [happens-before](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/memory.html#17.4.5) relationship so you can make certain guarantees about the ordering of your code.

In the code presented, the line:

```
X o = k.get("LL");
```

accesses the current X value for the key "LL". The next line modifies the a property. Without knowing the implementation of X, this is Java so we know that there is no method call here. *If* (and only if) the a property is marked as volatile then some subsequent code accessing the X at "LL" will see the a value as 6. If it isn't volatile then there are no guarantees at all. They will probably see 6, particularly on an SMP x86 box, with not many threads doing much at the time. In production, on a big NUMA box, they are less likely to. Mutability brings with it all sorts of complications and difficulty.

Generally, you'll find it is easier to reason about the state the map is in if you use immutable keys AND values.

Comment: How does accessing create a happens - before, the javadoc, says the happens- before is for writes/adds.

Comment: Well, the docs state "Actions in a thread prior to placing an object into any concurrent collection happen-before actions subsequent to the access or removal of that element from the collection in another thread." so you're correct that there is no guarantee that writes to a mutable value will necessarily piggy-back off just accessing the same value in a concurrent collection. As Rich Hickey says, we invented mutable values, we should uninvent them.

Answer (score 2):

The ConcurrentHashMap guarantees that getting a value is atomic, but it can't control what you do with the values you get from it. Modifying values in the hashmap is fine from the ConcurrentHashMap's view but may still not result in the behaviour you want. To be sure about thread-safety you need to consider exactly what each thread that has access to it does.

Putting the value back in the ConcurrentHashMap seems redundant and doesn't make the whole operation any safer. You're already modifying the object outside of any synchronization.

Additional synchronization may be necessary, but I can't tell for sure without seeing more context.

Comment: X x; line 3: synchronized(k){ x = k.get("LL");} line 12: synchronized(k){x.a++;} first thread goes through line 3, second thread goes through line 3 when thread 1 is at line 5, thread one alters x.a, then thread 2 alters x.a, what happens?

Comment: is the only way to do this (++x.a twice), to reset x in line 12: synchronized(k){x = k.get("LL); x.a++}?

Comment: @SamAdams In both examples, x will be incremented twice. But if you didn't have a synchronized block, one of the updates could have been lost.

Comment: and for reads: X x; line 3: synchronized(k){ x = k.get("LL");} line 12: synchronized(k){if(x.b){x.b = false;}} first thread goes through line 3, second thread goes through line 3 when thread 1 is at line 5, thread one alters x.b to false, what x.b does thread 2 see- i'll ask this in another question.

Answer (score 1):

Simply speaking:

```
  o.a=6
```

is an atomic operation, all the threads will compete, and the last thread setting it will "win", overwriting the value.

More specifically, the ConcurrentHashMap only guarantees that the link between a key and its associated value is handled taking multiple threads into account - ie **put and get are atomic**.

This does not prevent any thread from modifying attributes of the value once it gets a reference to it!

Comment: what about synchronized(o){o.a = 6;}?

Comment: @SamAdams that means that you can be 100% sure that `o.a`'s value is `6` within the entire synchronized block.

Comment: it depends - o.a=6 is executed by the main thread, there is no guarantee the other threads will not modify the value right after.

Comment: To explain better, the concurrenthashmap only guarantees the link between a key and its associated value is handled taking multiple threads into account. It does not prevent you modifying attributes of the value once you get a reference to it.

Comment: There is nothing to suggest that that is "atomic" or that there is any memory guarantees from setting it. In fact, there is no meaning without happens-before in the statement "the last thread setting it" as there is no negotiation between the threads on time. It is quite possible that several different threads could be using the same o and all have completely different values of o.a.

Comment: it still isn't atomic, volatile only gives you visibility guarantees

Comment: You are saying that assigning a constant value to a variable is not atomic? Can you explain? Anyway volatile was referring to  " It is quite possible that several different threads could be using the same o and all have completely different values of o.a", not to the atomiticy

Comment: "fields assignment is always atomic except for fields of long or double" - got it.

Comment: Actually, it turns out volatile ensure atomicity of assignment on long and doubles as well http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7 .

Comment: It is atomic for a very uninteresting value of atomicity. You aren't combining things, eg a read of the old variable state, computing a new value and then setting it. All you are doing is assigning six. If all your program ever does is assign six to the variable, then you have a linearizable program ie. you can tell whether that part of the code ran or not. If you have some other code that sets it to seven, you have no idea of or control over whether your six setting code ran or not – you have a race condition.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_operation