# concurrency java

Tags: java, concurrency

```
static ConcurrentHashMap k;

X x; 
//line 3: 
synchronized(k){ x = k.get("LL");}

// line 5 

// line 12: 
synchronized(k){if(x.b){x.b = false;}}
```

'k' is a shared map. First thread goes through line 3, second thread goes through line 3 when thread 1 is at line 5, thread one alters x.b to false, what x.b does thread 2 see? Line 5 is meant to show that thread 2 gets its x before thread one got in the second synch block

Comment: I would assume x.b would be false for thread 2... it's the same object

Comment: If this his homework, go head and tag it as such

Comment: not homework but thanks for the compliment on the question.

Comment: Why `synchronize` on a `ConcurrentHashMap`?  The whole point of `ConcurrentHashMap` is to not have to lock the entire map.

Comment: @KevinDay: [The `homework` tag has been deprecated. It should not be added to questions anymore.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)

Comment: possible duplicate of [concurrenthashmap java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13215264/concurrenthashmap-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have somewhat overspecified the terms "first thread" and "second thread"; your question presupposes that the first thread to enter the first `synchronized` block will also be the first thread to enter the second `synchronized` block, but there's really no reason to expect that.

However, the first `synchronized` block doesn't do anything very relevant or interesting — nothing in your code-snippet mutates `k`, and the first `synchronized` block merely accesses it — so I'm just going to ignore the fact that it's `synchronized`. That will simplify the definitions slightly: now "first thread" means the first thread to enter the second `synchronized` block, and "second thread" means the second thread to enter the second `synchronized` block. (O.K. so far?) That matter of definition out of the way . . .

Assuming that there's no possibility of some other thread coming in and setting `x.b` to `true` — or, for that matter, of the *first* thread doing so, in code that's after the snippet that you quote — and similarly, no possibility of the two threads getting completely different results for `k.get("LL")` due to things going on elsewhere — then the second thread will see `x.b` as `false`, just as one would naïvely expect. This is because

> If one action *happens-before* another, then the first is visible to and ordered before the second.

and

> An unlock on a monitor *happens-before* every subsequent lock on that monitor.

(Both of the above quotations are from [§17.5.5 of *The Java Language Specification*, Java SE 7 Edition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5); see that section, and the section before it, for more formalities.)

Comment: no, assuming x.b is true( it said thread one alters x.b to false, meaning x.b had to be true before the if statement). And no thread 1 accesses the synchronized block after thread 2 already accessed the line 3 statement, meaning it already has a reference to x, before thread 2 changes x.b value to false. assume the code above is a class, and each thread has its own instance of it (k still shared).

Comment: @SamAdams: Sorry, I don't understand your comment at all. To start with -- which part of my answer are you commenting on?

Comment: after the (O.K so far part), not ok.

Comment: @SamAdams: What's not O.K.? It would help if you quoted specific sections of my answer, and used complete sentences in replying to those sections . . .

Comment: Sure thing. "'first thread' means the first thread to enter the second synchronized block". Ya, but also that it enters that second synchronized block (in this hypothetical run), after the 'second thread' already got its x reference, which happened after the 'first thread' got its x reference

Comment: @SamAdams: Well, my point is that nothing in your code-snippet affects the result of `k.get("LL")`, so unless some *other* bit of code might come in and do that while *this* bit of code is running, the two threads' `x` will necessarily both refer to the same instance (or else both be `null`). So we don't need to bother specifying details like "[the first thread] enters that second synchronized block (in this hypothetical run), after the 'second thread' already got its x reference, which happened after the 'first thread' got its x reference", because we'll get the same result regardless.

Answer (score 1):

The explanation isn't exactly clear but here's what I understand it to be.

Since thread 1 is at line 5 (already through line 3) and hasn't yet hit line 12 (and your saying somewheres in between 3 and 12 thread 1 sets x.b to false), thread 2 should see x.b as whatever thread one just set it to (which is false). Though I don't see that thread 2 actually cares to see x.b in line 3. And it's not clear to me why line 5 (which I don't see) is not synchronized, yet line 12 which sets it to false is synchronized.

Comment: line 5 is meant to show that thread 2 gets its x  before thread one got in the second synch block

Comment: I think it would be good if you edit your code block to show this.

Comment: Well, that wasn't helpful at all.